# Website not returning data that I want using beautifulsoup, but it shows up fine in my browser

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to scrape some data from this website but getting a 403 error. When I open it in my browser its not giving me the error. Help would be appreciated. This is my first time trying any web scraping. I think I need something different in my header? not sure. thanks

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

pp_props_url = 'https://api.prizepicks.com/projections?league_id=7&per_page=250&single_stat=true'
headers = {
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
'Referer': 'https://app.prizepicks.com/',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
}


url = 'https://api.prizepicks.com/projections'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(r)
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['data'])
print(df)
```

I get a 403 error and its not returning the data I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

pp_props_url = 'https://api.prizepicks.com/projections?league_id=7&per_page=250&single_stat=true'
headers = {
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
'Referer': 'https://app.prizepicks.com/',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
}

r = requests.get(pp_props_url, headers=headers)
print(r)
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['data'])
print(df)
```

Comment: No that's still not working. I see the confusion though, the url variable is the same as the pp_props_url its just defined earlier in the code, sorry

Comment: Yes, it is working - just tested it. Just copy paste it as I wrote it above, and it should work. If not, then there is a problem with your IP, and you should try it over a VPN.

Comment: alright thanks its working now. I had tried it already but I guess there was something else in the notebook messing it up, on a fresh page it works fine. marked it solved